# Replace new line with n in Java

Tags: java, android, json, newline

I'm using Android Studio and I'm trying to pass a multi-line `EditText` field to a `JSON` string.

The problem I'm having is that line breaks within the `EditText` aren't being formatted as `\n` when being passed to the `JSON` string and the `JSON` then breaks.

I can't figure out how to replace an actual line break, with `\n` from the `EditText.getText()` so I can pass it correctly to the `JSON`.

To add some extra clarity.. The user types in:

"This is a note.

This is a few lines down"

This is being passed exactly as above to the `JSON` string. I need to format those line breaks to "\n" so they don't break the `JSON`

Comment: Can you share that part of the code where you are trying?

Comment: A simple string replace works. editText.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\n", "\n"); Something like this

Comment: Well how do they look, the line breaks within an EditText? You forgot to tell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing other linebreak symbols : `EditText.getText().replaceAll("\r\n|\r", "\n");`

Answer (score 1):

use `\\n`for escaping `\` in `\n` in Java or Android character escape have to do